# Content are not removing when i'm going on next tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  <body>

<div class="container">        

    <div id="page-content" class="header-clear">

        <div id="page-content-scroll"><!--Enables this element to be scrolled --> 


            <div class="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <ul class="tabs padding-tab">
                        <div class="col-xs-4 orange-tab current text-center" data-tab="tabs-1">
                            <li class="tab-link" >Step 1</li>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 orange-tab text-center" data-tab="tabs-2">
                            <li class="tab-link" >Step 2</li>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 orange-tab text-center" data-tab="tabs-3">
                            <li class="tab-link" >Step 3</li>
                        </div>

                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="tabs-1" class="tab-content current">
                    <div class="tab-elements">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-2" class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-elements">
                        dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
                        nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-3" class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-elements">
                       a commodo consequat.
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And here is the JS code

```
$('ul.tabs div.orange-tab').click(function(){
            var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

            $(this).parent().parent().find('ul.tabs div.orange-tab').removeClass('current');
            $(this).parent().parent().find('div.tab-content').removeClass('current');

            $(this).addClass('current');
            $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
        });
```

What I want is when i'm press on button (Step 2) to remove the .tab-content from tab number one, and to put the content from tab 2, I have no idea why but is not removing the 'current' class.

Comment: Because there is no  `div.tab-content` child of the `.content` (`$(this).parent().parent()` of `orange-tab`)

Comment: @A.Wolff and how can I slove that, i've tried a lot of solution

Comment: You are using IDs in HTML markup, so use it because anyway IDs must be unique on document context: `$('#page-content').find('div.tab-content').removeClass('current');`. But in more generic case, the more relevant transversal method would be [closest(selector)](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: @A.Wolff i've tried your solution with $('#page-content').find('div.tab-content').removeClass('curr‌​ent'); ..but still not working:(

Comment: I've no idea how do you test it because as i see it, it would work... Maybe you are using duplicate IDs or you have cache issue or...

Comment: @A.Wolff i've changed the line $(this).parent().parent().find('div.tab-content').removeClass('current'); with what you gave me

Comment: @Shold1934 ul tag should have li tag as its immediate child and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at my solution

```js
$('ul.tabs div.orange-tab').click(function(){
            var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

            $('ul.tabs div.orange-tab').removeClass('current');
            $('div.tab-content').removeClass('current');

            $(this).addClass('current');
            $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
        });
```

```css
div[id^="tabs"] {
    display: none;
}
div[id^="tabs"].current {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">        

    <div id="page-content" class="header-clear">

        <div id="page-content-scroll"><!--Enables this element to be scrolled --> 


            <div class="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <ul class="tabs padding-tab">
                        <div class="col-xs-4 orange-tab current text-center" data-tab="tabs-1">
                            <li class="tab-link" >Step 1</li>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 orange-tab text-center" data-tab="tabs-2">
                            <li class="tab-link" >Step 2</li>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 orange-tab text-center" data-tab="tabs-3">
                            <li class="tab-link" >Step 3</li>
                        </div>

                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="tabs-1" class="tab-content current">
                    <div class="tab-elements">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-2" class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-elements">
                        dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
                        nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-3" class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-elements">
                       a commodo consequat.
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is another snippet wich not requires a context, effects are applying to `id`-s and by condition when `.current` style is unknown.

```js
$('ul.tabs div.orange-tab').click(function(){
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('div.tab-content').hide(500);
    $("#"+tab_id).show(500);
});
```

```css
div[id^="tabs"] {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">        

    <div id="page-content" class="header-clear">

        <div id="page-content-scroll"><!--Enables this element to be scrolled --> 


            <div class="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <ul class="tabs padding-tab">
                        <div class="col-xs-4 orange-tab text-center" data-tab="tabs-1">
                            <li class="tab-link" >Step 1</li>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 orange-tab text-center" data-tab="tabs-2">
                            <li class="tab-link" >Step 2</li>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4 orange-tab text-center" data-tab="tabs-3">
                            <li class="tab-link" >Step 3</li>
                        </div>

                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div id="tabs-1" class="tab-content" style="display: block;">
                    <div class="tab-elements">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-2" class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-elements">
                        dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
                        nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="tabs-3" class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-elements">
                       a commodo consequat.
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ya, i suspect OP doesn't need more context to match relevant DIVs

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: 
There is no need of using

```
$(this).parent().parent().find();
```

If you are removing the classes on all the divs then just use:

```
$('ul.tabs div.orange-tab').removeClass('current');
$('div.tab-content').removeClass('current');
```

Hope this helps!